# What is the proper way to integrate templates into an existing Angular 2+ app?

Tags: angular, templates, angular-components

I have an Angular 4 application and I would like to improve the UI dashboard.

I came across [this dashboard from Creative Tim](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/light-bootstrap-dashboard-angular2) which claims it is built for Angular 2+. However when I download it, it appears to be its own standalone project. I am not sure how to integrate it into my existing app (i.e. I only need *some* of the components and features it includes and I don't want to make a huge mess of my app)

What is the proper way to copy over the parts you need and make sure they work?

Answer (score 4):

Usually templates are used when you start with a project. In such cases you can use the same project and create new components by editing the corresponding components in the template project.

In your case I would recommend you to add the required packages to your current project and then add the classes that are used in the template project to your project.

**Steps to be followed:**

- Install the packages that are not in our `package.json` by checking the
  template project package.json.
- Add the `.css` and `.js` files in the styles and scripts fields in your project `angular-cli.json`.
- If there is a similar component in your project which you want to  style, then add that class your project component.
- If you want to completely use a fresh component then copy the   corresponding component and styles into your project.

Comment: When I am importing the styles of the template, my styles for my initial pages are being ruined. The template styles are overriding them. Any solution?